# Why isn't my object being added to the array?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, nsmutablearray

I am not able to add objects to a simple NSMutableArray. I have an objective-c reference next to me and have it working for simple string. But I need to add actual objects. Please tell me what I am doing wrong here.

Code:

```
TBXMLElement *hubImage = [TBXML childElementNamed:@"image" parentElement:[TBXML childElementNamed:@"images" parentElement:pieceXML]];
if(hubImage) {
    do {
        HubPieceImage *tmpImage = [[HubPieceImage alloc] initWithXML:hubImage];
        [self.images addObject: tmpImage];
        HubPieceImage *tmpImage2 = [self.images lastObject];
        NSLog(@"image  : %@",  tmpImage.asset_url);
        NSLog(@"image 2: %@",  tmpImage2.asset_url);
    } while ((hubImage = hubImage->nextSibling));
}
NSLog(@"count  : %i", [self.images count]);
```

Returns this in log as it loops through two objects:

```
image  : http://farm6.static.flickr.com/5215/5533190578_4v629a79e5.jpg
image 2: (null)
image  : http://farm3.static.flickr.com/2774/5416668522_fdcr19aed3.jpg
image 2: (null)
count  : 0
```

Actually the array seems to not fill up at all (considering count:0)

Thanks for the help

Comment: What does the implementation of self.images look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I found the problem!**
I didn't initialize the array like so:

```
self.images = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

Comment: You will probably want to add an `-autorelease` message if it is a retained property.

Comment: Don't forget to accept your answer so that people don't think this question is still unsolved.

Answer (score 2):

Just for fun try this:

```
    HubPieceImage *tmpImage = [[HubPieceImage alloc] initWithXML:hubImage];
    NSAssert(self.images, @"Whoops! self.images is NULL");
    [self.images addObject: tmpImage];
```

Just might be your problem! That is, self.images might be nil.

Answer (score 0):

```
images = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:10];
```

Please make sure you have called alloc and init before you